# Django extra_views - UpdateWithInlinesView: field doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have two models: UserPost and Image - they are in one-to-many relationship. I want to be able to update both of the models in one template so I followed the docs and tried to implement UpdateWithInlinesView from extra_views but I got an error: `Unknown field(s) (image) specified for UserPost` Anyone knows what's happening?

**models.py**

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
user_id=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
...and some other fields

class Image(models.Model):
 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 user_post=models.ForeignKey(UserPost,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='images/')
 def __str__(self):
    return self.user_post.title
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('home')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImageInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
model = myModels.Image
fields = ['user_post','image']
```

**views.py**

```
class PostUpdate(UpdateWithInlinesView):
model=shopModels.UserPost
form=myForms.UploadPostForm
inlines = [myForms.ImageInline]
template_name = 'update_post.html'
fields=['image']
def get_success_url(self):
    return redirect('home')
```

**update_post.html**

```
{% extends './base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form }}
  {% for formset in inlines %}
    {{ formset }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that third party library you used for inlines, but it looks like error happens because of `fields=['image']`, where `image` field is not a field on `UserPost` that's defined as model for a view.

Comment: According to [this](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/formset-views.html#createwithinlinesview-and-updatewithinlinesview) example you should define other models fields in their inline classes, but not in `UpdateWithInlinesView` class

Comment: Thank you very much ! I defined fields for the Image in a wrong place... I fixed that and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I actually defined wrong fields in a view- I was supposed to define fields from a parent model. (Didn't read the docs carefully enough)

**views.py**

```
class PostUpdate(UpdateWithInlinesView):
model=shopModels.UserPost
form=myForms.UploadPostForm
inlines = [myForms.ImageInline]
template_name = 'shop/update_post.html'
fields=['title','text','category','is_used','price','first_image']
def get_success_url(self):
    return redirect('home')
```